# PyCharm Pro ImportError and Broken Virtualenv

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Issue: 
The solution was to uninstall the virtualenv.

While I was trying to set-up a `Django Project`. On the `manage.py`:

```
ImportError("Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
"available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? `Did you "`
"forget to activate a virtual environment?"

) from exc
```

Update: I ran `virtualenv cmd` in `Pycharm Pro terminal`
This came up:

```
You must provide a DEST_DIR
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR
```

installation and `virtualenv` is installed.

Comment: Is your PyCharm configured to use a virtualenv inside your project directory, or is it using the 'system' libraries?  If system libraries, have you *installed* Django requisites from PyPI into your environment with `sudo pip3 install` and such?

Comment: Checking the project the new environment using virtualnev is ticked for python and Django both inside the project directory.

Comment: Going onto Pycharm Pro Project Interrupter. I had only had the two installed packages (not Django or virtualnev). I need to install some more packages.

Comment: Yes.  You will need to drop into the PyCharm Pro 'Terminal' which will drop you into your venv.  Then install Django and its requisites.

Comment: I was following the instructions and installed them from project interperter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broken `virtualenv` was causing the `import error` the whole time. The only solution was to uninstall the virtualenv and it's dependencies. 
Here's all the `cmd` I used tried with in order:

```
    sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python-virtualenv 
    sudo apt-get remove python-virtualenv
    sudo apt-get remove virtualenv
```

To ensure all the virtualenv was uninstalled.

The `python3 venv` still remains as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

`from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line` works perfectly plus you are getting the following error when using python3.7 interpreter in Ubuntu 19.04:

```
You must provide a DEST_DIR
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR
```

The PyCharm terminal is like the default Ubuntu terminal except that it can be used within the PyCharm application. It looks to me like there is a typo in your question and instead of running `virtualenv cmd` which would have worked in the terminal you ran `virtualenv` which wouldn't have worked.

You got the following additional error in PyCharm.

```
ImportError(Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and  
available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to
activate a virtual environment?)
```

That looks like another typo error. The correct command to import Django is `import django` not `import Django`.

If `import django` doesn't work either then you need to tell PyCharm to look for Python packages that were installed from the default Ubuntu repositories when you create a new project. If any of the project's Python packages are installed from the default Ubuntu repositories PyCharm will find them automatically if you select the *Inherit global-site packages* option when you create a new project.

Select *File* -> *New Project* to create a new project. Click the triangle marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot to show the new project's options.

[image: Create Project]

Then check the *Inherit global-site packages* checkbox and click the  <kbd>Create</kbd>  button in the lower right corner of the Create Project window.

[image: Create Project options]